# Homework task- backtracking through an int method

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, backtracking

The following code is intended to bring you from `[0,0]` to `[a.length-1][a[0].length-1]` in a 2D array through the fastest route. Rules are that you can only advance left\right\up\down, and the next cell must be >(bigger) than the current cell.

```
    private static int path(int[][]a,int i, int j, int count)
    {
        if((i==a.length-1)&&(j==a[0].length-1))
            return count+1;
        if((j<a[0].length-1)&&(a[i][j]<a[i][j+1]))
            if(canPass(a,i,j+1))
                return (path(a,i,j+1,count+1));
        if((i<a.length-1)&&(a[i][j]<a[i+1][j]))
            if(canPass(a,i+1,j))
                return path(a,i+1,j,count+1);
        if((i>0)&&(a[i][j]<a[i-1][j]))
            if(canPass(a,i-1,j))
                return path(a,i-1,j,count+1);
        if((j>0)&&(a[i][j]<a[i][j-1]))
            if(canPass(a,i,j-1))
                return path(a,i,j-1,count+1);
         return -1;
private static boolean canPass(int[][]a,int i,int j)
    {
        if((i==a.length-1)&&(j==a[0].length-1))
            return true;
        if((j<a[0].length-1)&&(a[i][j]<a[i][j+1]))
                 if(canPass(a,i,j+1))
                    return true;
         if((i<a.length-1)&&(a[i][j]<a[i+1][j]))
                 if(canPass(a,i+1,j))
                    return true;
         if((i>0)&&(a[i][j]<a[i-1][j]))
                 if(canPass(a,i-1,j))
                    return true;
         if((j>0)&&(a[i][j]<a[i][j-1]))
                 if(canPass(a,i,j-1))
                    return true;
         return false;
        }
public static void main(String args[])//DRIVER
    {    
       int[][] multi = new int[][]{
  { 3, 13, 15, 28, 30 },
  { 40, 51, 52, 29, 30 },
  { 28, 10, 53, 54, 53 },
  { 53, 12, 55, 53, 60 },
  { 70, 62, 56, 20, 80 },
  { 80, 81, 90, 95, 100 },
};
System.out.println(path(multi));
```

This code works. However, two things I'm not happy with and would appreciate your help:

1. The `return -1` line at the end of the method- is it essentially never called? How can I avoid it?
2. The use of a boolean method- I tried to make the backtracking work with just an `int` method but couldn't come across a solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive implementation here could use a little work,.. or rather a little less work!

In the `canPass` function you do the entire recursive evaluation of the grid. You do all the work necessary here to find a valid path. If the path is possible you then move one block in the `path` function and forget about all that work you did. On the next step you re-evaluate the whole grid again. This is way way too much work, and as the size of the grid increases your implementation is going to become very slow.

Ideally for this program you only need the one recursive function. The `canPass` function should just tell you if the next square is possible. It really only exists so you don't have to write out the conditions 4 times in a row. If no paths are possible return -1 to show it is invalid. And also instead of passing the count down to other functions, just increase it as you return.

Here's an example approach:

```
public static boolean canPass(int[][]a, int i, int j, int oldValue){
    if((j >= a[0].length) || (j < 0) || (i >= a.length) || (i < 0)){
        return false;
    }
    return a[i][j] > oldValue;
}

// added a helper function to reduce repetitive code
public static int chooseShortest(int nextPath, int currentPath){
    if (nextPath != -1){
        if (currentPath == -1 || currentPath > nextPath){
                return nextPath;
            }
        }
    }
    return currentPath;
}

public static int path(int[][]a, int i, int j)
{
    // This is the end condition
    // there is one step left so return 1
    if((i == a.length - 1) && (j==a[0].length - 1)){
        return 1;
    }

    int shortestPath = -1;

    if (canPass(a, i, j + 1, a[i][j])){
        shortestPath = chooseShortest(path(a, i, j + 1), shortestPath);
    }
    if (canPass(a, i, j - 1, a[i][j])){
        shortestPath = chooseShortest(path(a, i, j - 1), shortestPath);
    }
    if (canPass(a, i + 1, j, a[i][j])){
        shortestPath = chooseShortest(path(a, i + 1, j), shortestPath);
    }
    if (canPass(a, i - 1, j, a[i][j])){
        shortestPath = chooseShortest(path(a, i - 1, j), shortestPath);
    }
    // if all 4 paths return -1 there is no path possible from here
    if (shortestPath == -1){
        return -1;
    }

    // return the shortest path + 1 step to get there
    return shortestPath + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Just one question: The condition     `if((j >= a[0].length) || (j < 0) || (i >= a.length) || (i < 0))` shouldn't be && instead of ||? Since you only need one of these conditions to take place, not all of them together. Thank you!

Comment: @roony `||` means "or" so thats exeactly what it does. If j is too big or j is too small or i is too big or i is too small return you cant pass